# How to express temperatures greater or less than

Tags: single-word-requests

How do you correctly describe a 'minus' temperature when comparing to another 'minus' temperature? For example, is -20C '>' or '<' -15C?
The temperature is warmer, so therefore, is it greater than -20?

Comment: Mathematical convention ... -20 < -15, so use that.

Comment: Non-mathematically too, we all know that -20 is less than, colder than, -15.

Comment: Temperatures are higher and lower not greater and smaller.

Comment: Note that there's nothing wrong with "warmer"/'hotter" and "cooler"/"colder", even in a formal context.

Answer (score 8):

Although there are contexts when it feels natural to say *greater* even though what we mean is *greater in magnitude* (i.e. *greater in absolute value*), everyday thermometry is **not** one of those contexts, and the usual mathematical convention applies.

We would say that -20 °C is **lower than** -15 °C or, equivalently, **less than** -15 °C.
   (-20 °C < -15 °C)

Conversely, -15 °C is **higher than** -20 °C or, equivalently, **greater than** -20 °C.
   (-15 °C > -20 °C)

Here are some examples:

> Heterogeneous nucleation is most likely at temperatures **less than** -10 C (especially around -15 C)… [(US National Weather Service)](https://www.weather.gov/lmk/winter-precip)
>
> Temperatures **less than** -30 °C (-22 °F) can occur, but typically only once in five years. [(Current Results)](https://www.currentresults.com/Weather/Canada/New-Brunswick/Places/moncton-temperatures-by-month-average.php)
>
> Wind chill temperatures **less than** -20F are considered low, temperatures **less than** -40F are extreme and temperatures **less than** -60F are considered dangerous. [(Unisys Weather)](http://50.206.172.193/surface/sfc_con.php?image=wc&inv=1&t=cur)
>
> Their results indicated that minimum temperature was probably the factor limiting mistletoe distribution. Temperatures **less than** -39 °C were lethal to *A. americanum,* and temperatures **less than** -29 °C were lethal to *A. douglasii.*  [(*Dwarf Mistletoes: Biology, Pathology, and Systematics*)](https://books.google.com/books?id=bdfXQ4c5h4IC&lpg=PA65&dq=%22temperatures%20less%20than%22&pg=PA66#v=onepage&q=%22temperatures%20less%20than%22&f=false)
>
> The damage to blueberries, though, was not nearly as bad as he expected going into the season because of temperatures **greater than** minus-20 degrees Fahrenheit. [(Farm World)](http://www.farmworldonline.com/News/NewsArticle.asp?newsid=24291)
>
> Concentrated orange juice shipped at temperatures **greater than** minus 18 degree Celsius would be classified as “not frozen” orange juice as opposed to “frozen.” [(US Department of Argiculture)](https://apps.fas.usda.gov/gainfiles/200501/146118558.pdf)
>
> Butter shall not be held under long storage at temperatures **greater than** minus 10° Celsius. [(*Dairy Industry Regulations 1977,* Western Australia)](https://www.legislation.wa.gov.au/legislation/prod/filestore.nsf/FileURL/mrdoc_2894.htm/$FILE/Dairy%20Industry%20Regulations%201977%20-%20%5B00-x0-02%5D.html?OpenElement)

**Discussion**

As I said, there indeed are contexts when it feels natural to say *greater* even though what we mean is *greater in magnitude.* In such contexts, saying *less* while referring to negative numbers can cause confusion. One example: suppose we want to say that in order for an electrical spark to occur, a particular object must carry enough negative charge. If we say *a spark will occur if the total charge is less than -3 C,* this sounds confusing. To prevent confusion, what we may say instead is this: *a spark occurs when the **magnitude** of the negative charge exceeds 3 C.*

But for such confusion to be possible, it must be meaningful to talk about the *magnitude*  of a quantity that can be either positive or negative.

Thermometry is not one of those contexts.

On the one hand, if one is using the Celsius or Fahrenheit scale, then the magnitude of temperature is not meaningful. (Some would say that these scales are examples of ['interval scales'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Interval_scale), although that 'typology of measurement' is controversial.)

On the other hand, if one is using the absolute temperature scale (i.e. kelvins or degrees Rankine), then the magnitude of temperature *is* meaningful (according to the aforementioned typology of measurement, these are ['ratio scales'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Ratio_scale)). But in this case there can be no confusion, because the absolute temperature *normally* cannot be negative (but see the Appendix).

**Appendix: negative absolute temperature**

There do exist some special situations in which it is useful to define [negative absolute temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_temperature). But negative absolute temperatures don't "work" as you might expect: namely, *any negative absolute temperature is actually **hotter** than any positive absolute temperature*.

At this point I face a choice: I can either try to explain this puzzling statement, or not. I choose the former; this being an appendix, the uninterested can always stop their reading here.

I hope the following explanation has a shot of being understandable by quite a few people, especially those who have had at least some exposure to high school-level physics and/or chemistry.

The situations where it makes sense to define negative absolute temperature occur in physical systems which (for a fixed number of constituent particles) have an upper bound on the total amount of energy they can have, and into which the experimenter (or nature) can actually put an amount of energy comparable to that upper bound.

Textbook examples are systems composed of particles that have a finite number of [energy states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_level), so that the maximum energy corresponds to all particles being in the highest energy state.

Note that ordinary [gases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas) are ***not*** such systems, since there is no upper bound on the amount of [kinetic energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy) that a molecule in a gas can have.

As an example of a system that ***does*** have a finite maximum energy per particle, consider a [system composed of nuclear spins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_temperature#Nuclear_spins) (each of which carries an associated magnetic moment) in an external magnetic field, and such that the interactions between the spins themselves are negligible. The maximum energy of the system then corresponds to all spins oriented so that the associated magnetic moments are all pointing in the direction opposite to that of the external field.

In situations where we decide to introduce negative absolute temperature, the potential for confusion (when it comes to the terms *greater than* and *less than*) is even greater than usual, because of the peculiar way how negative temperatures 'work'. To prevent confusion, it is better to think about a quantity proportional to the *inverse* absolute temperature. This quantity (sometimes called the *coldness*) is denoted *β*. It is related to the absolute temperature *T* through the Boltzmann constant *k*<sub>B</sub>:

*β* = 1/(*k*<sub>B</sub> *T* ).

From the standpoint of fundamental physics, *β* is more meaningful than the absolute temperature *T* itself. In particular, it is always correct to say that the *lower* the *β,* the *warmer* the object, even as *β* turns negative. Basically, *β* measures [relative occupations of energy levels in a system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution): if *n*<sub>A</sub> is the occupation of a level of energy *E*<sub>A</sub> and *n*<sub>B</sub> that of a level of energy *E*<sub>B</sub>, then

*n*<sub>A</sub>/*n*<sub>B</sub> = *e* <sup>*- β* *(E*<sub>A</sub>-*E*<sub>B</sub> *)*</sup>.

So for 'normal' systems, the lower-lying energy levels are more occupied than the higher-lying ones, and so *β* is positive (and so is the absolute temperature; the two always have the same sign).

Let's follow what happens as *β* is lowered from positive infinity to zero to negative infinity:

When *β* is positive infinity (absolute temperature *T* equal to zero), only the lowest-lying energy level (the ['ground state'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_state)) is occupied.

Next, let *β* be positive and finite (so *T* is positive and finite as well): in principle, all energy levels are occupied, but the *lower* the level, the more occupied it is. This is the 'usual' situation, occurring in a vast majority of physical systems. The bias towards the occupation of lower levels decreases as the system gets warmer—i.e. with decreasing positive *β* or, equivalently, with increasing positive *T*.

As we keep lowering *β* closer and closer to zero (corresponding to increasing *T* higher and higher without bound), the higher energy levels get to be more and more occupied. It is still true that the higher the energy level, the lower its occupation, i.e., the level occupation decreases as a function of the level. However, if we look at the *rate* at which the level occupation decreases as a function of the level, we see that this rate becomes smaller and smaller as *β* becomes smaller and smaller (while remaining positive).

When *β* reaches zero (corresponding to *T* reaching the positive infinity), all energy levels are equally occupied.

Now suppose we make *β* negative, but finite in magnitude (so that *T* is also negative and finite). In this case, the *higher* the level, the more occupied it is. Such a situation is often called ['population inversion'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_inversion); the most famous example where it occurs is in [lasers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser#Gain_medium_and_cavity).

Note that as *β* goes *continuously* from small-and-positive to zero to small-and-negative, the change in the actual physical properties is also continuous: we go from a situation where the *lower* the level, the *slightly* more occupied it is, to one where all levels are equally occupied, to one where the *higher* the level, the *slightly more* occupied it is. These changes may involve arbitrarily small increases and decreases in the total energy: if we start from the situation where an isolated system has *β*=0 so that all levels are equally occupied, then any decrease in the total energy of the system, no matter how small, will result in *β* becoming positive, and any increase in the total energy, no matter how small, will result in *β* becoming negative.

Meanwhile, for the same kind of change in *β* (or in the total energy), the absolute temperature has a *jump discontinuity* from the positive infinity to the negative infinity. This is one reason why *β* is arguably a better parameter than the absolute temperature.

Finally, if *β*  is negative infinite, then only the highest energy state is occupied. This corresponds to the absolute temperature going to zero from the negative direction.

Note that in systems in which negative temperatures are possible, saying that the system has zero absolute temperature is actually ambiguous. The positive infinite *β* corresponds to the absolute temperature going to zero from the positive direction, while the negative infinite *β* corresponds to the absolute temperature also going to zero from the negative direction. So we can't simply say that the temperature is zero; we must specify whether it reached zero by approaching it from the positive or the negative direction. Also note that the actual physical circumstances corresponding to *β* being positive infinite and negative infinite are vastly different: in the first case, only the lowest energy level is occupied, while in the second, only the highest is. The *β* scale appropriately sets these two situations infinitely far from each other (as +∞ and -∞), whereas the absolute temperature scale, counterintuitively, sets them infinitely close to each other, at 0<sup>+</sup> and 0<sup>-</sup> (here 0<sup>+</sup> means the [limit approaching zero from above](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit), and 0<sup>-</sup>, from below).

Here are the trajectories of *β* and of the absolute temperature as we go from a maximally cold system to a maximally hot one. Note that *β* changes continuously, while the absolute temperature has a jump discontinuity from positive infinity to negative infinity.

| *β* | *T* |
| --- | --- |
| +∞ | 0<sup>+</sup> |
| finite pos. | finite pos. |
| 0<sup>+</sup> | +∞ |
| 0<sup>-</sup> | -∞ |
| finite neg. | finite neg. |
| -∞ | 0<sup>-</sup> |

The moral of the story: when negative absolute temperatures are present, in order not to be driven insane, forgo the absolute temperature in favor of *β.*

Comment: When you adjust the thermostat to make it cooler, do you say you turn it up or down?

Comment: @livresque As far as the thermostat, for cooling, you turn it *down*; see e.g. [here](https://www.hallsair.com/blog/does-turning-my-thermostat-down-lower-cool-the-house-faster/) and [here](https://www.accomfort.us/blog/air-conditioning-service/heat-goes-up-dont-crank-thermostat-down/). However, thereby you turn the *cooling* **up**; see e.g. [here](https://www.nbc12.com/story/38447259/how-to-properly-use-your-ac-save-energy-on-hot-days/).

Comment: Perhaps greater than necessary.

Comment: Parts of this answer are [unreadable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FV1X.png). Please don't use spacing like that; we're not all looking at this from a device exactly like yours.

Comment: @Laurel It should be OK now.

Comment: "(-20 °C < -15 °C)" is still weirdly spaced, as is the similar line two beneath that.

Comment: @Laurel That, too, should be fixed now. (And thank you for suggesting the use of table formatting!!)

Comment: Yay for collaboration! It looks a lot better now.